# How can I turn a vector layer into a graph G = (V, E)?

Tags: python, shapefile, network, graph

I have a number of rail networks, in the form of shapefiles of the "line" type. I want to turn them into a more abstract graph format, i.e. the kind with vertices and edges, not chart-type graphs. Moreover I want these data to be usable outside my GIS programs, in Python. Basically what I want is to extract something along the lines of the TSPLIB format, except with only vertices and edges. For my immediate purposes, I don't even need weights or anything. Just the topology.

Is there any relatively pain-free way to do this in QGIS or GRASS? I haven't quite lucked out yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) ( A python module for the creation, manipulation, and study of the structure, dynamics, and functions of complex networks ) has a [read_shp()](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/nx_shp.html) function which generates a graphs from shapefiles. You might want to check it out. Here's a [short tutorial](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs224w/nx_tutorial.pdf).

No TPSLIB export as far as I know but does support writing the graphs into formats like GML, GraphML, Pickle, adjacency lists, and GEXF to name a few. The full list of output formats can be found [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/index.html). I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: I tried that and it isn't doing quite what I need—the situation is made more complicated by the fact that I'm not entirely sure what I actually NEED for my inquiry—but it's a lead and I appreciate it. I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

To turn your lines into edges, and give them an id, you may want to use `assign_vertex_id` inside PostGIS in case your lines are in PostgreSQL/PostGIS.
Using that, you will get a unique id for your rail network lines.
To get the vertices i.e. start and end point of the lines you can simply add two extra columns for them and run a simple update to fill values in those columns.

I hope that helped! 
Merry xmas! ;)

Comment: You seem to be describing the *dual* of the graph. To create the graph of the question, you need to assign unique identifiers to *vertices*--giving the same ID to any coincident vertices--and edges need no identifiers at all.

Comment: I don't know anything about the PostGIS stuff but I will say thanks and merry xmas likewise.